# how can i save the primary key of a entity in another entity when entity framework is saving

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

so I have this problem I am doing an import and I need when save the first table that primary key of the first table save too in another table that is not a foreing key ,  is a way that EF do that? Iam using EF5

is something like this, note that entity1.id is autoIncrement

```
foreach (var entity1 in Entities1)
                {
                    DbContext.Entity1.Add(entity1);
                    var entity2 = new Entity2();
                    entity2.Entity1Id = entity1.id;
                    DbContext.Entity2.Add(entity2);
                }
                DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

Id is not generated until SaveChanges is called. So for this code to work, you have to rewrite it down like this:

```
DbContext.Entity1.Add(entity1);
DbContext.SaveChanges();
var entity2 = new Entity2();
entity2.Entity1Id = entity1.id;
DbContext.Entity2.Add(entity2);
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```